# Make single column of Grid View hierarchical in WPF UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

I am implementing a nested gridView in which I have to make 1 column of nested grid hierarchical, but not able to do so. Currently I am using telerik for WPF UI. I have a picture of expected result which I am attaching for reference.
[Image for expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMDfy.png)

this image is just for reference, and I want to replicate that grid, also I don't have code for the grid showed in image.

I have implemented a telerik tree view before also drag and drop feature on it, and it works perfectly fine, the code to make a treeItem hierarchical is:

```
<controls:TreeView Name="trvProcess"  ItemsSource="{Binding lstDroppedProcessItem}"      telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="False" IsDragDropEnabled="True" SelectedItem ="{Binding       SelectedTreeItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <controls:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </controls:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource ="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </controls:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:TreeView>
```

it yielded perfect results:
[TreeView Hierarchical Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPBJX.png)

I followed the same thought process and tried to add a hierarchical Data template in a cell template of GridViewDataColumn code for which is:

```
<controls:GridViewDataColumn Name="colProcessId"
      Header="Process ID"
      IsResizable="True"
      IsFilterable="True"
      IsFilteringDeferred="True"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      DataMemberBinding="{Binding Target.PRCS_ID}"
      Width="Auto"
      FieldName="PRCS_ID"
      EntityName="ProcessQueue">
    <controls:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource ="{Binding ChildProcessQueueRequests,    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Target.PRCS_ID}"  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </controls:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</controls:GridViewDataColumn>
```

But it does not seem to work so far I have been able to achieve following result:
[Image of achieved result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrdnX.png)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<controls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>` instead of `<controls:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>` ?

Comment: You need a control that is able to present a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Such a control could be the `HeaderedItemsControl ` or the `TreeVie`. Make such a control the content host of the particular column. For example, define a `DataTemplate` for the cell template. Add a * TreeView` to this `DataTemplate`. Define an implicit (keyless) `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and assign it to the the `TreeView.Resources` dictionary.

Comment: @Ostas I also tried with CellTemplate, it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get desired results by defining a TreeListView as,

```
<telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
    <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding ChildProcessQueueRequests, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition>
</telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
```